# What exactly is a "guest pass" or "starter edition" and how do I give it to a friend?

Tags: diablo-iii

I've seen "Diablo III guest passes" mentioned as a way to allow friends to experience a "demo" of the game. I have purchased Diablo III but going over my Battle.net account page I cannot find any way to give such a pass to a friend.

- What, exactly, does a guest pass mean? Is it time limited? Content limited? Both?
- How do I give such a guest pass to a friend?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

These are guest passes:

[image]

I had 3 of them in the retail boxed version of the game.  Each one has a one-time-use code, which allows another person to download the game, and play it with certain restrictions.

On the back, it reads:

> The guest account allows you to play Diablo 3 for free up to the Skeleton King boss in Act 1.  Note that certain game features are restricted on guest accounts - to remove these restrictions, please upgrade to the full version of the game.

[Blizzard's FAQ on this system](http://us.battle.net/support/en/article/diablo-iii-starter-edition-guest-pass) says that the Guest Pass grants you the "Starter Edition" of the game, and says the following about restrictions:

> - Act I up to the Skeleton King is available
> - Level 13 cap
> - Matchmaking available only with other Starter Edition players
> - No Real Money Auction House access
> - Global Play is not available. Players attempting to connect to Diablo III Starter Edition in a region other than their Battle.net Account's home region will receive Error 12. See the Global Play support article for more information.

No Guest Passes are included with the downloadable version that you can purchase directly from Blizzard.

Some related Guest Pass questions:

[Do guest pass characters carry through an upgrade to the full game?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/68022/do-guest-pass-characters-carry-through-an-upgrade-to-the-full-game) 
[Does a Diablo 3 guest pass let you play with regular players?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/68039/does-a-diablo-3-guest-pass-let-you-play-with-regular-players)

Comment: Before you get excited and try to redeem the code on the right, I already gave that one away in chat the other day :)

Comment: Do characters carry over from the starter version to the full version if you upgrade?

Comment: *Matchmaking available only with other Starter Edition players*: Does this mean that you can only play with other SE players (so you can't join a game with your friend who has the full version), or doe sit only apply to PUGs?

Comment: If you have the full version, you *can't* play with Starter Edition players.  If you buy the CE, and give the included three passes to your friends, they can play together, but can't play with *you*.

Answer (score 4):

A guest pass allows someone who hasn't bought Diablo 3 to play the Starter Edition. It is very similar to the beta - max character level is 13, and it ends once you defeat the Skeleton King.

You get two guest passes when you buy the retail version of the game. Unfortunately the download version does not come with any guest passes.

Comment: Is it time-limited in any way?

Comment: @Oak - I believe it's time limited in the sense that Blizzard has said that, within the next month or so, you won't NEED one of these passes to get the Starter Edition.  It never runs out, though.