# I bought Diablo 3 from Blizzard, do I get guest passes?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What exactly is a “guest pass” and how do I give it to a friend?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67974/what-exactly-is-a-guest-pass-and-how-do-i-give-it-to-a-friend)

I bought Diablo 3 from Blizzard's online store. Does this give me access to "guest passes" available in the retail boxes to let friends try out the game?

And if so, where do I find them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you do not get access to guest passes in the digital download version of Diablo 3. They are only in the retail version.

Comment: Which is pretty retarded. Blizzard makes much more money from people buying it online so they should get them, too.