# Do guest pass characters carry through an upgrade to the full game?

Tags: diablo-iii

If a player starts playing Diablo 3 with a guest pass, and later purchase the full game, do the character(s) created with guest pass remain playable with full access to content?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you login to your battle.net account on their website you will be able to upgrade to the full game via an option on the right hand side of your Diablo III Starter Edition game management screen.
According to a post that has become [inaccessible](http://diablo.incgamers.com/blog/comments/diablo-3-starter-edition-and-guest-passes-explained), you will be able to carry over your progression to the full game.

Answer (score 5):

I did this and while i could carry over my character, it seems that i have to do the quest again from scratch (but with my already level 10 character)