# Where can I find the starter edition keys?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What exactly is a “guest pass” and how do I give it to a friend?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67974/what-exactly-is-a-guest-pass-and-how-do-i-give-it-to-a-friend)
>   [Do guest pass characters carry through an upgrade to the full game?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/68022/do-guest-pass-characters-carry-through-an-upgrade-to-the-full-game)

I;ve read that with every copy of diablo3, there are 2 starter edition keys for you to give to other people, but I cannot find them.

Do you know where can I get them?

And, if the user changes from starter to standar, will he preserver their players?

Comment: Do you have the digital edition? In that case, no keys for you.

Comment: On the other hand, give it a few months and Blizzard will be giving these away like it's going out of style. :)

Comment: I have the physical edition, but I dont have it here with me, somebody received it and sent me the key