# Does a Diablo 3 guest pass let you play with regular players?

Tags: diablo-iii

Can people using guest passes interact with people with the standard game?

Specifically, if I give one to a friend, can we add each other as friends, and play a game together (up to the Skeleton King only of course)?

Comment: I don't why blizzard would put a restriction on this. I mean after all people can communicate via other means...

Comment: possible duplicate of [What exactly is a "guest pass" and how do I give it to a friend?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67974/what-exactly-is-a-guest-pass-and-how-do-i-give-it-to-a-friend)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Per their official [website](http://us.battle.net/support/en/article/diablo-iii-starter-edition-guest-pass):

> - Act I up to the Skeleton King is available
> - Level 13 cap
> - **Matchmaking available only with other Starter Edition players**
> - No Real Money Auction House access
> - Global Play is not available. Players attempting to connect to Diablo III Starter Edition in a region other than their Battle.net Account's home region will receive Error 12. See the Global Play support article for more information.

"Starting Edition" player, meaning players using the guest pass. So you are limited to interacting with them only.

Comment: I saw that in the FAQ, but I wasn't sure if that meant the default matchmaking, or if it totally prevented you from playing with friends with the standard version. Has anyone tried this in-game?

Comment: `So you are limited to interacting with them only.` I think that's pretty self explanatory. :P

Comment: This limitation is clearly to prevent AH abuses, like listing more than 10 items per account (bought game). Otherwise everybody would create starter edition accounts to sell level 60 items.

Comment: No, you can't play with your friends who have the full version either. I've tested it.

Answer (score 6):

Players using the guest pass are restricted to playing with other guest pass users. You can not play or trade between the normal game and the guest pass version