# Can Starter Edition/guest pass characters carry into the Standard Edition?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do guest pass characters carry through an upgrade to the full game?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/68022/do-guest-pass-characters-carry-through-an-upgrade-to-the-full-game)

My friend is using one of my guest passes. Will she be able to bring her character into the main game with [the rest of us](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/68039/21177) if she purchases the full game, or must she start anew?

Answer (score 0):

On the back of the guest pass, it says:

> *2.* Create a Battle.net account or log in if you already have one.

So, they must have a Battle.net account to play.

> Note that certain game features are restricted on guest accounts – to remove these restrictions, please upgrade to the full version of the game.

Therefore, it seems that the guest pass user may continue to play the game from where they left off after purchasing the game.

I also believe that StarCraft II guest passes worked like these for the singleplayer campaign.