# Is it somehow possible to lease the game for a weekend?

Tags: diablo-iii

I want to play on a LAN (with internet connection) with some friends. They do not want to buy the game, as it is quite expensive. Is there some way to lease it for some days?

I heard there are some solutions for Starcraft 2 in south america, does this also apply to Diablo 3 in Europe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you cannot play Diablo 3 or Starcraft 2 on a LAN. You are required to connect to Battle.net (be online). A lot of people disagree with this decision on Blizzard's part but it's the way the game is designed.

Secondly, as Ben said, you cannot "borrow" the game. But what you can do is get some [Diablo 3 Guest Passes](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67974/what-exactly-is-a-guest-pass-or-starter-edition-and-how-do-i-give-it-to-a-fr), which let you download and play the game for free within certain limits.

For Starcraft 2, you can actually just get the [SC2 Starter Edition](https://us.battle.net/account/sc2/starter-edition/) for free. Eventually Blizzard will probably do the same thing for Diablo 3, but for now you need to get a guest pass.

Comment: As already stated we have an internet connection we just want to hang out together. But Guest Passes look promising.

Comment: My apologies, I saw the mention of the LAN and assumed you wanted LAN play, and all SC2 and D3 play has to talk to the server. A lot of people sell or give away their guest pass codes online, by the way.

Comment: @Wikwocket - As an aside... I'm sure selling those guest passes for profit is highly illegal.

Comment: @Tater596 I'm not sure actually. I don't know if the TOS/EULA cover the guest passes. The guest passes are not part of your game or battle.net account... maybe selling them is more like selling the Diablo-themed pad of paper that came in the box?

Answer (score 1):

Legally, this is against the Blizzard ToS, since leasing or renting it would require someone to let you use their account for a price.

[Blizzard Terms of Service](http://eu.blizzard.com/en-gb/company/about/termsofuse.html)